# Dispatch dictionary (HomeWork)

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x

```
def get_map_iterator(slist,gfunc=None):
index = 0
def Next():
    nonlocal index
    x = slist[index]
    index = index + 1
    return x
def has_more():
    if slist[index] != None :
        return True
    else:
        return False

dispatch = {
'Next': lambda: gfunc(Next()),
'has_more': has_more
}
return dispatch

it = get_map_iterator((1,3,6))
for i in range(i,6):
it['Next']()

it = get_map_iterator((1,3,6),lambda x:1/x) 
while it['has_more'](): 
it['next']()
```

p.s
the results of of this code should be :

```
1
3
6
no more items
no more items

1.0
0.33333
0.166666
```

How does the change to gfunc will affect this, i mean what will i will need to change in order for this to work if i do get a  func or i dont get  a func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_map_iterator()` returns a function object (`dispatch`). You are trying to treat that object as if it was a dictionary.

You want to *call* it instead:

```
while it('has_more'):
    it('Next')
```

Your `dispatch()` function does not itself return another function object, so you'd not call whatever `it()` returns.

Your `has_more` route then fails with:

```
>>> it('has_more')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in dispatch
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in has_more
TypeError: next expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

presumably because you meant to use the `Next()` function you defined, not the built-in [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

However, even fixing that won't get you your output, because `slist[0] != slist[1]`.

It sounds as if you were trying to actually return a *dictionary*:

```
dispatch = {
    'Next': lambda: gfunc(Next()),
    'has_more': has_more
}
return dispatch
```

This return value you *would* use like you did originally, by looking up the callable via a key, then calling it.

Comment: Yes i have noticed that thank you, there is allso another problem.    'TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable'

Comment: @Mike.G: remove the `()` at the end, you are not returning functions.

Comment: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable - now this error have droped by with the changes that you have told me to do

Comment: @Mike.G: I did say you had to go back to your original code, so use `it['has_more']()` and `it['Next']()`.

Comment: when i am useing that im getting the bool is uncallable.

Comment: @Mike.G: then you are still returning *called function results*, not the function objects themselves.

Comment: @Mike.G: note that my dispatch dictionary contains *function objects*. `has_more` is *not* being called, and `gfunc()` is wrapped in a lambda.

Comment: Edit : found the problem , had to change the if condition from slist[next()] to slist[index]

Comment: How would it affect me if i will set the gfunc = None at the top and then will just want to iterate on the list i am getting?

Comment: @Mike.G: If you leave `gfunc` set to `None` you'll have to provide an alternative version; `if gfunc is None: gfunc = lambda arg: arg` to return the value unchanged.

Comment: Am i allowed to make if statments in the value in this case ? 
i mean  : 'Next': if gfunc == None : gfunc = lambda x:x else: lambda : gfunc(Next())

Comment: @Mike.G: just set `gfunc` before you create the dictionary. You can use a conditional expression too, but that would not be that readable.